# All my DNS A records are accessable from web browser

Tags: .htaccess, dns, apache2

I haven't got a great understanding of DNS so bear with me, but can someone explain how I can prevent all my default DNS A records (mail, ftp, ns1, ns2, etc.) from loading my homepage?

For instance, currently ns1.mysite.com loads the homepage. I want to strictly enforce it so only mysite.com loads the homepage, while also allowing uploads.mysite.com or blog.mysite.com to work as well.

I would like it so ns1.mysite.com results in:

[image: http://cdn.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/this-webpage-is-not-available.jpg]

or 'ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT', instead of my homepage or my server's default 404.html page.

Answer (score 2):

What you are planning to do can only be achieved if you use IP-based virtual hosting, but then you must ensure that only the names you use for web serving are pointing to the IP address that you run your web server on.  Nothing else, not even smtp.

Something like:

```
www1 IN a 192.0.2.100
www IN a 192.0.2.100
@ IN a 192.0.2.100
```

And everything else must be on a different IP:

```
mail IN a 192.0.2.3
ns IN a 192.0.2.3
ftp IN a 192.0.2.3
ns1 IN a 192.0.2.3
```

For that, you will need two separate IP addresses, which is very uncommon - but it may be workable if you let your host (or any other provider on a different IP address) to run all your other services.  But this also means you cannot run any other services *with a different name* but port 80 HTTP (and port 443 HTTPS) on `192.2.0.100`.  Otherwise that service will need a name that can then be used from a browser.

For a browsing session to actually time out on the other names, you also need control over the firewall to drop packets to TCP port 80 on the IP address `192.2.0.3` (which I would personally consider overkill).  You cannot make the resolution to fail for these names, or they would not be usable for their purposes.  But not running HTTP/HTTPS service on that other IP address would just show connection rejected/refused, which I would consider acceptable.

But, even if you can get more IP addresses for this purpose, you will still need to combine this with *name based virtual* serving.

That is, you need to make sure your web server will only handle your traffic when reached by the names designated by you as web server names.

You still need to consider what happens if you use IP addresses to go to your site, or if I use my domain `funny.example.com` to point to your server's IP address, and configure a catchall/default/wildcard server with a custom error page.

On the other hand, if you cannot have one more IP address, with the aid of the names, you still can have a custom error page showing that there is no service available on the names you don't control, or you don't want to use for web serving.  Or just simply redirect all such traffic to your canonical name, which seems to be the most common usage to me.

Comment: I can't do multiple IP addresses. I guess I'll have to redirect to the site root (fixing the URL) if someone tries to access one of these special subdomains. If it's any help I have full shell access to the server, I'd imagine there must be some hacky way to make it timeout on requests for specific subdomains.

Comment: In the catchall service, you can do something processing longer than the usual browser timeout.  Most languages provide a feature, usually called sleep.  However, this would be at the expense of keeping the socket and the handling process in memory for the whole time, making it much easier for any attacker to launch a DoS attack against your server.